# Where did I make a mistake in this transformation of random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, trigonometry, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The arctangent of a standard Cauchy random variable $Z\sim\text{Cauchy}(0,1)$ is uniformly distributed in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.  The proof is straightforward:

$$P(\arctan(Z)\leq t)=P(Z\leq \tan t)=\frac{t}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}.$$

Now, standard Cauchy random variable is the ratio between two i.i.d. standard normal random variables, that is, if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then $X/Y\sim\text{Cauchy}(0,1)$.  The arctangent of $X/Y$ should thus also be uniformly distributed in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.  However, when I evaluate the CDF explicitly, I obtain:

$$\begin{align}
\tag{1}P(\arctan(X/Y)\leq t)&=P(X/Y\leq\tan t)\\
\tag{2}&=P(X\leq Y\tan t)\\
\tag{3}&=P(X-Y\tan t\leq 0)\\
\tag{4}&=\frac{1}{2},
\end{align}$$

where (4) is because $X-Y\tan t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1+\tan^2t)$ by the additivity of i.i.d. normal random variables.  Clearly I made a mistake somewhere, however, I am not sure where.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Going from $\frac{X}{Y}\leq \tan t$ to $X\leq Y\tan t$ isn't valid if $Y<0$.

Comment: You can't go from (1) to (2) because you don't know the sign of $Y$